# Sockets - What is the failure rate?

Tags: java, sockets

I have a Java socket client talking to a socket server written in another language. I am running this on Linux.

Java client is coded with test logic - establish client connection from java to the other language, send dummy string to server, get dummy string back - close client socket - loop.

After millions of calcs and around 7 hours, I got a read timeout on java side.

Don't have any monitoring tools right now to see if GC came in the way or something else.

- Whats the general expectation here? should it run forever until server space runs out or some other external factor interferes?
- How do I make this communication reliable? any best practices for fault-tolerance to be coded here?

---

**Adding replies here to comments below:**

Thanks everyone for responding. Yes, exceptions are being catched and logged- that's how i came to know about the socket read timeout error. and yes, connection was established, send also happened and then the read timeout occurred (as per read timeout error).. so that's puzzling - if the server was having problems, the connection would not be successful or something else would go wrong before sending/reading data. Also, there was no error on the server - the server has a 10s write timeout, but even then there was no error - not sure why. java has 2 min read timeout - and still threw the error.

I had only put in error logging and not debug/info level. no errors were there on the server application, only java client threw error and then it kept on throwing a read timeout for 1 hr. So, that's again weird - java kept on connecting and sending test string and had problems receiving the data? and server never complained? i can code fault tolerance to say if read timeout then wait some time and then try again - but not sure if this would completely solve my problem. sadly the server can't be rewritten to keep the socket open.

Comment: "After millions of calcs and around 7 hours, I got a read timeout on java side." - you mean a read timeout from the socket? How long do you have left the sockets open? Please show a minimal example code.

Comment: read timeout means no connection with remote server... mayby you should provide better try/catch and open/close for inputstreams and not to have this kind of problems (I think 99% of problems comes from closing properly streams).

Comment: @ArdiGoxhaj A read timeout means there *is* a connection, as far as this end can tell, and the peer didn't respond within the timeout period. Neither try/catch nor open/close has anything to do with that.

Comment: You are correct server didn't respond to client, I said that maybe better try/catch mechanism open/close should fix the issue, however http://www.javaworld.com/article/2076498/core-java/simple-handling-of-network-timeouts.html expains how to deal. Usually when you don't close files/inputstreams the memory run out. If you need to provide better or fault tolerance mayby try/catch is the best approach when a read timeout occurs catch the exception increment a variable initialized with 0 and you could see how many times the timeout occured, then you can try to establish a new connection.

Comment: @ArdiGoxhaj Read the question. He *is* establishing a new connection. Over and over again. And obviously he *is* catching the exception. Otherwise he wouldn't know about it. Your cited link from 15 years ago is mostly drivel, starting with the startling claim that 'non-blocking I/O ... can be activated on any Socket, ServerSocket, or DatagramSocket'. It can't.

Comment: Thanks everyone for responding.
Yes, exceptions are being catched and logged- that's how i came to know about the socket read timeout error.
and yes, connection was established, send also happened and then the read timeout occurred (as per read timeout error).. so that's puzzling - if the server was having problems, the connection would not be successful or something else would go wrong before sending/reading data.
Also, there was no error on the server - the server has a 10s write timeout, but even then there was no error - not sure why. java has 2 min read timeout - and still threw the error

Answer (score 0):

> Whats the general expectation here? should it run forever until server space runs out or some other external factor interferes?

Exactly, and it looks like exactly that has happened. You would need to look at the server side logs to see exactly why it hasn't responded.

> How do I make this communication reliable? any best practices for fault-tolerance to be coded here?

It would be better to use a single connection for as long as possible, rather than a new one per request, if the server supports it.

Comment: I had only put in error logging and not debug/info level.
no errors were there on the server application, only java client threw error and then it kept on throwing a read timeout for 1 hr. So, that's again weird - java kept on connecting and sending test string and had problems receiving the data? and server never complained?
i can code fault tolerance to say if read timeout then wait some time and then try again - but not sure if this would completely solve my problem.
sadly the server can't be rewritten to keep the socket open.